# Error 150 when adding FOREIGN KEY to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm not sure why I ALWAYS have problems with FOREIGN KEYs, but I'm having one again.

When I run:

```
ALTER TABLE wishlist ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id);
```

I get:

```
Can't create table (errno: 150)
```

Both tables exists.  Both columns exists, and they are both the same type - bigint(20).  user.user_id is the primary key, but wishlist.user_id is not.  Both are `NOT NULL`

Here's the start of the user table (I have truncated it for easy of reading):

```
+-----------------+------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| user_id         | bigint(20)                   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| salt2           | varchar(24)                  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| gender          | enum('MAN','WOMAN','EITHER') | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| user_name       | varchar(255)                 | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| password        | varchar(255)                 | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| user_email      | varchar(255)                 | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| phone           | varchar(20)                  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
```

And the `wishlist` table:

```
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| wish_id   | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| link_hash | char(32)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id   | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am not creating a table that was being dropped.

Comment: Can you show the table definitions?

Comment: Are you recreating a table that was dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using InnoDB, the user_id column has to be of type "key" or "primary key", not type bigint. That particular engine does not like creating FK constraints on non key items.

```
CREATE TABLE 'user' (
 KEY 'user_id' ('user_id')
 [... your columns here]
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Also, ensure both are using the same engine and charset, otherwise it will still fail.

Comment: has to be unique or primary,just an index wont cut it.

Comment: Very interesting - but how do I know if I'm using InnoDB?  Or, perhaps more directly, how do I MODIFY the current table for `user_id` to be of type PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'user' to find the engine and ALTER TABLE user
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id) to convert the existing column. Make sure you have backups first!

Comment: Thank you.  My two tables were of different types - as this is one of my first dips into MySQL, that would have otherwise taken me a LONG time to figure out.  Thanks!